# Which are the different option to store image in android app from webservice?

Tags: android, image, caching, store, internal

I want to store some of the data from web service when it is loaded first time in android. I am storing data in shared preference and database. My data also consists of Images.Please suggest me the options to store image other than internal storage if possible and which would be efficient and light weighted ?
As Facebook also displays some of the images when the app is offline.

Comment: Try downloading images in an efficient way provided by [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)! And you can go with caching and storing them using third party libraries, like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)! and [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)!

Comment: If you don't want to use internal memory, -why not?-, then external and removable memory are the options left.

Comment: There is no any strict restrictions what to use and not to use...I am just searching for the different possible ways and which one will be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You must have to use lib for save image because we can not handle properly bitmap. Lib are following :-

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

[Universal Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

[Volley](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/volley-part-3-image-loader)

Above lib have own benefit so take who full fill your goal. You can save image on cache.

See below link :-

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: I am using volley library to fetch data and images from network.please provide reference in volley for storing image. I have loaded image using NetworkImageView of volley.